# Is it Safe to Fry Honey?

Tags: frying, pork, honey

I have honey and porkchops. Is it safe to marinate the porkchops in a honey based marinade and then fry them in a blend of cooking oils?

Comment: Are you saying you want to mix honey and oil, and use it as a frying medium?

Comment: Yes. Is that a safe thing to do?

Comment: It will almost certainly burn and scortch and be completely unpalatable.  And very difficult to clean.   Its probably safe within some particular definition of the word.  A fire extinguisher may be advisable.

Comment: Class B, suitable for oil fires.

Comment: I should probably revise my question. I marinated the porkchops in a blend of honey, soy, and other oils. I let that sit for about an hour. In volume, the sauce was probably about 25% honey. Then I fried the porkchops - they were cut thin - in that sauce. I stirred constantly and it didn't burn too badly at all. The taste was okay, though I should add more flavours (mustard, balsamic, etc.).

Comment: Sure, there is no reason to think there are safety issues.  Honey/soy is pretty cloying, so you might want some strong flavors like chili or garlic or ginger to (or all three) to help balance it out and give it complexity.

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear exactly what you want to ask if you still want answers.

Comment: "I should probably revise my question" is certainly correct. Since it has been a month and somebody else "bumped" the question by editing an answer, I took the liberty of editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of adding sugar to stir-fries, to make a caramel flavoured sauce/glaze in Vietnamese cooking, as in [this recipe](http://rasamalaysia.com/vietnamese-caramel-shrimp-recipe-tom-rim/2/).  Although I've usually seen sugar used, I see no reason why a similar effect could not be obtained by using honey.